# Finite graph products of finite groups have free subgroup of finite index

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is a problem in Hatcher's Algebraic topology.

Show that a finite graph product of finite groups has a free subgroup of finite index, by constructing a finite-sheeted covering space of $K\Gamma$ from universal covers of the mapping cylinders of $K\Gamma$.

I have absolutely no idea how the universal covers of the mapping cylinders look like when we don't know that the group homomorphisms are injective. And I have no idea how to construct this finite sheeted covering. Please help.

EDIT: $K\Gamma$ is the space made by placing any $BG\in K(G,1)$ at the place of $G$ and gluing the mapping cylinder of the induced morphism $BG\to BH$ at the place of edges $G\to H$. For detail see Hatcher 1B.7

Comment: Your title says "finite group products" and the text of your question says "finite graph products". Can you clarify?

Comment: Also, your question seems to refer to a specific $\Gamma$ and a specific $K\Gamma$. Not knowing what those objects are, it is hard to give any feedback.

Comment: @LeeMosher Please refer to hatcher 1b.7 for the construction of $K\Gamma$.

Comment: This does not answer the question; but I comment that another approach to graphs of groups which appeals to me and is purely algebraic is in  Higgins, P.J., "The fundamental groupoid of a graph of groups", _J. London Math. Soc_. (2), 13 (1976)  145--149. This gives the injectivity part of Hatcher's Theorem 1B.11.

Comment: It looks like the concept you are discussing is defined not in 1B.7 but in the paragraph just preceding Theorem 1B.11. Also, the phrase "graph product of groups" has a second, older, and entirely different meaning; an unfortunate clash of terminology which threw me off.

Comment: And it looks like the problem to which you are referring is problem 9 in the exercises at the end of Section 1.B. The hypotheses of problem 9 require the edge homomorphisms to be injective, which should clear up your first problem.